# Does a pure and nothrow function which does not pass out memory automatically collect garbage?

Tags: garbage-collection, d, purely-functional

Assume you have a function in D that is `pure` and `nothrow` and by its return type and argument types cannot pass out any newly allocated memory. Can I add the `@nogc` attribute to this function then? If not, are there chances that this will be possible in the future?

My point here is the following: Since the function does not have any visible side effects, all memory that was allocated on the way can be freed deterministically at function exit. Hence, the GC is not really required, since the mark and sweep step can be avoided. Or can it not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can always try adding `@nogc` and compiling. A pure function may still allocate internal buffers, even if it doesn't return any of them, so the question of garbage collection is on a different axis than purity.

If it passes compilation with `@nogc`, it will not allocate (and thus not collect, the D GC will only ever collect when you ask it to allocate) regardless of purity.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, but I think you've missed my point. Therefore, I clarified my question by adding some more text.

Comment: Ah, yeah, a pure function in theory should be able to use a region allocator for its whole call stack with a free at the end though I wouldn't expect this to be implemented automatically any time soon...

Comment: Or it could always allocate on the stack, and forget about freeing up memory?

Comment: @Tamas I don't think this would work, because some allocated memory needs to stay alive longer than the function that allocated it. This does not work with stack allocation. It could be a second stack though.

Comment: @AdamD.Ruppe Maybe, I'm a little green here, but implementing that kind of functionality does not seem too hard: The function at question needs to switch a thread-local flag in the garbage collector, telling it to allocate in a region allocator and then the function needs to clean up after itself at the end. The only thing I would be worried about are memory allocations in tight loops that produce too much garbage. But then again garbage collection could be done locally, which is much more efficient then a global collect.

Comment: Yeah, a second stack is more or less a region allocator. It shouldn't be too hard but it does need to be careful.. prolly the flag would be a counter that is added and subtracted to it can handle arbitrary depth of these strongly pure functions and the compiler would inc and dec it on function enter/exit. From there, the immutable+pure guarantees along with the return value not having indirection should be enough to guarantee no escaping references - but it must be strongly pure on the outside, weakly pure could still return through out prams. Then druntime uses the region and frees @ cnt==0.

Answer (score 2):

https://dlang.org/spec/attribute.html#nogc

> ... means that that function does not allocate memory on the GC heap,
>   either directly such as with NewExpression or indirectly through
>   functions it may call, or through language features such as array
>   concatenation and dynamic closures.

It doesn't tell anything about GC state after function execution or overall memory usage increase. Only thing that matters is that function itself is guaranteed to never call any GC allocation functions, i.e. you could reliably build and run such function with a custom runtime that doesn't have GC implementation linked in at all.

Another important point is that `@nogc` can't be affected by optimizations because same valid code must keep compiling with different optimization levels and different compilers. Any such optimizations would need to become mandatory in language specification before `@nogc` can take use of it.

With all that in mind your described function could get valid `@nogc` annotation only when both following conditions apply:

1. it doesn't actually make any GC calls at all, it is completely optimized out
2. such optimization is mandatory and is guaranteed to always happen in such cases for all compliant compilers by language specification

I see it as extremely unlikely.

Comment: That's correct with the current definition of `@nogc`. But on the other hand, one could redefine the meaning of `@nogc`, so that it means that no global freeze-the-world will take place and that the garbage collector will be in the same state after the function call that is was in at function entry. With that changed definition it might well be possible.

Comment: Considering @nogc was primarily introduced to appeal gamedev and embedded crowd, I'd expect such attempt to meet quite a lot of resistance.